# Keyboard shortcut to close the execution tab in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, user-interface, mysql-workbench

After i execute a query in mysql workbench, a tab pops up showing the result. How do i close it with a keyboard shortcut? Thanks!

see screenshot here:

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=23d51ff

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-keys.html

states that it should be Ctrl + W

Comment: yeah, but it's not. Ctrl + W closes the query tab and not the popup execution tab..

Answer (score 1):

There's no shortcut to close the resultset tab. You can only use ⌘ + W to close the owning tab (the editor tab). However you still can click the close button on the tab (right beside the title when you hover with the mouse over the tab) to close it.

Btw. on Windows it is not Ctrl + W but Ctrl + F4 (which is the system standard). The web page needs an update.

Comment: In Windows It doesn't work with control + f4 as of may 1, 2023. MySQL Workbench Ver. 8.0 But It does work with control + w

Answer (score 0):

on OS X create your own shortcut:

1. Apple menu -> System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts
2. plus button on the left
3. in 'Application' find mysqlworbench
4. in 'Menu Title' type 'View->Panels->Hide Output Area'
5. in 'Keyboard Shortcut'... You know what to do ^^

peace!